# jboss eap 7 - Post message to IBM MQ with resource adapter

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq, redhat, jboss-eap-7, wildfly-14

I have installed WMQ JMS resource adapter (9.0.4) to my JBOSS EAP 7 standalone-full.xml & created connection factory and admin object to it.

```
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=ibm-mq-resource-adapter:add(archive=wmq.jmsra-9.0.4.0.rar, transaction-support=NoTransaction)
```

```
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=ibm-mq-resource-adapter/admin-objects=queue-ao1:add(class-name=com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.MQQueueProxy, jndi-name=java:jboss/outbound)

/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=ibm-mq-resource-adapter/admin-objects=queue-ao1/config-properties=baseQueueName:add(value=TEST1)
/subsystem=resource-adapters/resource-adapter=ibm-mq-resource-adapter/admin-objects=queue-ao1/config-properties=baseQueueManagerName:add(value=TESTMANAGER)
```

Connection definition:

```
<connection-definition class-name="com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl" jndi-name="java:jboss/mqSeriesJMSFactoryoutbound" tracking="false" pool-name="mq-cd">
 <config-property name="channel">
                 SYSTEM.DEF.XXX
</config-property>
                            <config-property name="hostName">
                                XX-XXX
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="transportType">
                                CLIENT
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="queueManager">
                                TESTMANAGER
                            </config-property>
                            <config-property name="port">
                                1414
                            </config-property>
                        </connection-definition>
```

In my understanding, If I post a message to the outbound queue from the connection factory mqSeriesJMSFactoryoutbound, I should be able to reach IBM MQ. I tried with below code to look up connection factory but I am getting naming notfound exception. Please help

```
public class TestQueueConnection {

    // Set up all the default values
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Hello, World! successfull";
    private static final String DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY = "java:jboss/mqSeriesJMSFactoryoutbound";
    private static final String DEFAULT_DESTINATION = "java:jboss/outbound";
    private static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE_COUNT = "1";
    private static final String DEFAULT_USERNAME = "jmsuser";
    private static final String DEFAULT_PASSWORD = "jmsuser123";
    private static final String INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY = "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory";
    private static final String PROVIDER_URL = "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8070";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JMSException {

        Context namingContext = null;

        try {
             String userName = System.getProperty("username", DEFAULT_USERNAME);
             String password = System.getProperty("password", DEFAULT_PASSWORD);

            // Set up the namingContext for the JNDI lookup
            final Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, System.getProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, PROVIDER_URL));
            namingContext = new InitialContext(env);

            // Perform the JNDI lookups
            String connectionFactoryString = System.getProperty("connection.factory", DEFAULT_CONNECTION_FACTORY);
             namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);
            QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) 
            JMSContext jmsContext = connectionFactory.createContext(DEFAULT_USERNAME, DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
    

            Queue destination = (Queue) namingContext.lookup(DEFAULT_DESTINATION);
            
            jmsContext.createProducer().send(destination, DEFAULT_MESSAGE);
            System.out.println("><><><><><><>< MESSAGE POSTED <><><><><><><>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" );
            
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (namingContext != null) {
                try {
                    namingContext.close();
                } catch (NamingException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to have your connection factory with the exported name in it  for it to be accessible from the outside. So you should bind it to java:jboss/exported/mqSeriesJMSFactoryoutbound

Answer (score 0):

Made couple of changes to the above.

1. In connection-definition, instead of com.ibm.mq.connector.outbound.ManagedConnectionFactoryImpl, used Managed**Queue**ConnectionFactoryImpl to avoid class cast exception at runtime.
2. Connection factories created by RA are not accessible outside of its JVM. Written a servlet to access these connection factory. I am able to connect with below piece of code.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
        
        Context namingContext = null;
        String connectionFactoryString = "mqSeriesJMSFactoryoutbound";
        String queueName = "outbound";
        
        MessageProducer producer = null;
        Session session = null;
        Connection conn =null;
        try {
            namingContext = new InitialContext();
            
            QueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (QueueConnectionFactory) namingContext.lookup(connectionFactoryString);
            Queue destination = (Queue) namingContext.lookup(queueName);
            
            conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            session = conn.createSession(Boolean.FALSE, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            producer = session.createProducer(destination);
            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
            message.setText(msg);
            
            producer.send(message,
                    Message.DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE,
                    Message.DEFAULT_PRIORITY,
                    Message.DEFAULT_TIME_TO_LIVE);
            
                      
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        finally {
            
            // Close the message producer
            try {
              if (producer != null) producer.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException e) {
              System.err.println("Failed to close message producer: " + e);
            }
            
            // Close the session
            try {
              if (session != null) session.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException e) {
              System.err.println("Failed to close session: " + e);
            }
            
            // Close the connection
            try {
                if(conn != null)
              conn.close();
            }
            catch (JMSException e) {
              System.err.println("Failed to close connection: " + e);
            }
            
          }
        
        
        
        
    }
```